# Using Suite Setup and Test Setup together

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I have some precondition for Suite and they should be runs once per suite, so I will add on Suite Setup.
also, I have some precondition for each test-case and they should run at the start of each test-case.

**The question is if I use both of them, which one start first if I only run one of the test-cases? Suite Setup or Test Setup?**

something like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library ...
Varialbles ...
Suite Setup: suite_precondition
Test Setup: test_precondtion

*** Test Cases ***
TC1
<Some code>

TC2
<Some code>
```

You know that we can run TC1, or TC2 one by one for checking the test-case PASS or not. So what happened here when I run TC1?

Comment: Suite setup will always have higher priority as compared to Test Setup.
it does not matter if you run 1 Tc or all, Suite Setup will always run first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suite setup always runs before any tests start. After that, the test setup will run for each test when the test first starts.